# How to build a Dockerfile for an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API will multiple dependencies

Tags: docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my current Dockerfile configuration:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8443
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["QueryHub.API.csproj", "API/src/"]
COPY ["../../Application/src/QueryHub.Application.csproj", "Application/src/"]
COPY ["../../Domain/src/QueryHub.Domain.csproj", "Domain/src/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API/src/QueryHub.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API/src"
RUN dotnet build "QueryHub.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "QueryHub.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "QueryHub.API.dll"]
```

This is the error that I get:

```
 => CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/9] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/9] COPY [QueryHub.API.csproj, API/src/]                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [build 4/9] COPY [../../Application/src/QueryHub.Application.csproj, Application/src/]                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [build 5/9] COPY [../../Domain/src/QueryHub.Domain.csproj, Domain/src/]                                                                                     0.0s
------
 > [build 4/9] COPY [../../Application/src/QueryHub.Application.csproj, Application/src/]:
------
------
 > [build 5/9] COPY [../../Domain/src/QueryHub.Domain.csproj, Domain/src/]:
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |     COPY ["QueryHub.API.csproj", "API/src/"]
  10 |     COPY ["../../Application/src/QueryHub.Application.csproj", "Application/src/"]
  11 | >>> COPY ["../../Domain/src/QueryHub.Domain.csproj", "Domain/src/"]
  12 |     RUN dotnet restore "API/src/QueryHub.API.csproj"
  13 |     COPY . .
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 066d5801-db14-4bdf-93e4-426029f9558a::fh78pkkcdx5om457jxic3fc1y: "/Domain/src/QueryHub.Domain.csproj": not found
```

The relative path is correct.

This is my folder structure:

```
src
   API
      src
        csproj
        Dockerfile
    enter code here
        tests
   Domain
        src
        csproj
   Application
        src
        csproj
   Worker
```

I am try to build a image to deploy. My ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project is dependent on `Domain` and `Application` projects.

Is there any issue providing relative path from my dockerfile. What should I do?

Comment: The files you are trying to copy are in your folder structure.

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: `../../Domain/src/QueryHub.Domain.csproj` is in the `Dockerfile` but not in the folder structure.

Comment: But the path is relative to my Dockerfile

Comment: Docker say "file does not exists", your folder structure says: "the file is not there". You say "but the path is relative". How does that make sense?